# UIAlertView Display bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

Here is the thing...

I'm trying to programmatically display an UIAlertView with several subviews. It's being called from another UIAlertView using my UISignInView class (UIViewController with needed protocols)

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
UISignInView *signinview;
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        signinview = [UISignInView new];
        [signinview addLoginPopUp:self:0];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

And it's created using this function:

```
- (void)addLoginPopUp:(id) sender:(int) error{   
NSString * Msg;
double Yposition;
switch (error) {
    case 0:
        Msg = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        Yposition = 45.0;
        break;}

loginPopUp = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inscription"  
                                        message:Msg
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler"  
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

[loginPopUp addButtonWithTitle:@"S'inscrire"];
[loginPopUp show];

//Adding 3 UITextFields
login = nil;
login = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, Yposition, 264.0, 30.0)];
[loginPopUp addSubview:login];


password = nil;
password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, Yposition + 36, 264.0, 30.0)];
[loginPopUp addSubview:password];

repeat_password = nil;
repeat_password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, Yposition + 36 + 36, 264.0, 30.0)];
[loginPopUp addSubview:repeat_password];

//Adding 2 UISwitch
accept_appli= [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(179.0, Yposition + 36 + 36 +36, 64, 30.0)];
[accept_appli setOn:FALSE];
[loginPopUp addSubview:accept_appli];

accept_part = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(179.0, Yposition + 36 + 36 +36 + 33, 64, 30.0)];
[accept_part setOn:FALSE];
[loginPopUp addSubview:accept_part];

[loginPopUp release];
```

}

And the result is that the UIAlertView label goes like in a scrolling mode, and the buttons are not "down" enough.

I first thought of a "\n" limit but if anything goes wrong with the formular, this exact same UIAlertView is called back from the request done function, except everything is well displayed

Any Idea? I've been dealing with this for a while now...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out a way to prevent this from appenning...

Instead of adding the subviews in ViewDidLoad I added them in the ViewWillAppear function.

I guess its kind of a bug... and that in my previous code, the views were added at a wrong moment.

Hope it'll help!